# how to create a thumbnail video slider?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I wanted to make a thumbnail slider . I am trying the following code but it's not working it just showing me a black screen with a very long scroll bar.

`[I'm using this code](https://codepen.io/aykutkapisiz/pen/POGJxg)`

Comment: Hey, to answer your question, you need to provide a bit of your code for us to help. If you have followed the CodePen correctly, it should work, so here are some things that usually cause such an issue: Jquery is missing, image paths are wrong, CSS files are missing or incorrectly linked.

Answer (score -1):

your codepen is not include any videos, slider works ok but showing blank for this try like this

```html
<video id="video" controls="controls">
       <source src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JfJYHfrOGgQ" gesture="media" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen>
 </video>
```

Comment: Based on the CodePen, they provided, they are most likely looking for an image carousel instead of a video thumbnail.

Comment: but title of question is video thumbnail,  i think slider works ok . @Sonali needs video thumbnail in slider

Comment: @MAYURSANCHETI yes you are right i need videos in the slider

Comment: @Sonali is this answer helpful for you

Comment: yes but videos are not playing, I've added youtube videos.

Comment: try again i change code

Comment: Still not Working